# How do I make a graphical asset in Visual Studio update?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xna, edit

I'm working on an XNA project and modify a graphical asset outside of Visual Studio. In order for those changes to show up in the application, I need to remove the reference to the original image, and then re-add the same image to see the changes. This happens whether I do a complete rebuild or not. Is there a way to streamline this process so that my project shows the changes I've made without having to remove the content reference and then re-adding it after each change.

Comment: I do this all the time and never encountered this issue. What are the properties you set for your assets (textures?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XNA is pretty smart, and only wants to re-run assets through the content pipeline when it detects something has changed. For some reason it isn't seeing the changes you are making.

1. Make sure you are modifying the correct file. For example if your original image is at *c:\myImage.png* and your project is as *c:\myGame* when you add the image to the Content Project it gets copied to *c:\myGame\myGameContent*. Editing the image at c:\myImage.png wont get noticed. You need to edit *c:\myGame\myGameContent\myImage.png*
2. If you are editing the correct file and it still won't update, try touching another file. As smart as the engine is, it will run everything through the Content Pipeline when it detects 1 item has changed.* If that still doesn't work If you look at the top of the Solution Explorer there is a refresh button. Try pressing it as it should make sure your Solution Tree is in sync with the files on disk.

***note this is true for v3.1 it could have changed for 4.0**

Answer (score 1):

When you drag an item into a Visual Studio project (like, in this case, a Content Project), it will **copy the file into the project directory**. By default it does not reference the file you drag in (although that is available as an option).

(If the file you drag in is already in the project directory, it just leaves it there.)

The upshot of this is that you need to work on your content files in the content project directory, if you want to see your updates happen immediately.

If you don't know where the files are being copied to, select one of them in your content project and press F4 (properties window). Find the "Full Path" entry. That is where your files are stored.